# Is there a way to cast regex groups into Typescript types?

Tags: regex, typescript

Suppose I have the following string:

`"A   D"`

And I apply the following RegExp:

`/([AB]) *([CD])/`

This will either return null, or return an array of strings representing the groups. The first group will always be either "A" or "B", in my case "A". The second group will always be "C" or "D".

As such I would like the following:

```
const str = 'A    D'
const groups = new RegExp('([AB]) *([CD])').exec(str);
return groups[1] === 'Q'
```

This should give me a typescript error, but it doesn't. I want it to give me ts(2367), this condition will always return 'false' since types groups[1]: "A" | "B" and "Q" have no overlap.

Is there **nice** way I can have typescript pull the group types out of my regexp?

Comment: Groups are strings, accessed via some particular and unspecified key (numbered or named), and the entire regex pattern is itself parsed from some arbitrary string with domain-specific rules. Such groups (much less semantically logical overlap) is _outside_ of the type system, so there is no “should” here: that’s not how TS is expected to work.

Answer (score 4):

Not really - TypeScript doesn't try to interpret patterns, and the shape of `exec` is:

```
exec(string: string): RegExpExecArray | null;
```

where `RegExpExecArray` is:

```
interface RegExpExecArray extends Array<string> {
    index: number;
    input: string;
}
```

`.match` isn't any better.

If your pattern, when executed, produces an output of certain types, you'll have to specify them explicitly *in addition* to the pattern, eg:

```
const groups = new RegExp('([AB]) *([CD])').exec(str);
if (groups) {
    const typedGroups = [...groups] as [string, 'A' | 'B', 'C' | 'D'];
```

It's not very pretty, but there aren't really any good options here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! With a few limitations. I have a "generic" solution, for a subset of inputs. It is similar to @Guilhermevrs but I was able to push it to be more general.

You can take a regular expression (as a string) that uses named groupings, and can then produce a typed `groups` object. Ultimately, you need a recursive type that builds the record. I ended up with a "type" that converts a regular expression to a type record:

```
type ExtractGroupNames<S extends string> =
  S extends `${string}(?<${infer Name}>${infer Rest}`
    ? (Record<Name, string> & ExtractGroupNames<Rest>)
    : Record<never, any>
```

I was able to get `exec` to return a strongly typed record that properly auto-completes and complains about incorrect fields!

There's a little bit of leg work to get it to plug into the standard regular expression code (if you want). I've documented it thoroughly here: https://blog.ndpsoftware.com/2022/10/strong-typing-regexp

You could probably do something similar with traditional, indexed, capture groups, but I didn't do this. It seems like it's going to have many caveats. But if your regular expressions are like `(A|B)`, this would be possible to pull these apart into types, using similar to code to the blog post.

Answer (score 2):

As @CertainPerformance indicated, `RegExpExecArray` is not very nice in terms of typing, indeed.

What you could do, though, is to use [Named Groupings](https://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-named-capture-groups.html)

```js
const str = 'A    D'
const test = /(?<firstGroup>[AB]) *(?<secondGroup>[CD])/.exec(str)

const groups = test?.groups;
/**
 * Groups is of type {[key:string]: string} | undefined
 */
interface RegexResult {
    firstGroup: 'A' | 'B';
    secondGroup: 'C' | 'D';
}
const myResult: Partial<RegexResult> | undefined = groups;
```

You need to target es2018 for that to work.

[Here is an example in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOMC8MDkBBGWYBFUFgAoUSWKAU2mRgHoAKAfgB4AzAS3mgHF4QBXAA4A%20ANroAQgF0AlDABUjJhHIkAJj37CRAYRwyaAOnIAPFXQTSiRElQDmvQRGoVoDA-c0QA3ERpy5RPIwGo4wbE4gLDBQAJ4C5DAA3iIA1uQxAFwIbGC2khlwUPA5tgC%20MAA%20MHxgquTsYOSqgXI0RDkU8CwAhsAJAErktiaDEHwANrCJgdjsnFAhAgUYqJVo4qg%20hNhwKuDqDkto2qtVqHhbpdbgVAC2MaMTUAUACt3wUGzd40yDw8aPSZCNY1OoNJrUDyOLxAA)

Comment: This is pretty good. But it will fail if I change either the interface or the regex. I don't think much more can be done though, after digging in a bit it doesn't seem like there's anyway around it unless you could extend the typescript compiler.